# Loop through an array in user model to find a match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, where-clause

I am a bit new to Rails console as a UI Engineer but, I am trying to loop through each user, and find within a specific array of products if the products array contains a couple product ids. Because the products array is no more than 20 values, the products array is a part of the user model. for ex --

users purchase products 801,808,902

a user could have a products array that contains [800,801,802,808,809...]

i want to find all users that contain either 801, 808

for those that match the set, associate a new product for all these users (a free gift)

I wanted to apply it via the production rails console as a quick script

thanks for the help in the right direction!

I tried to do the following -- 
      `User.where(:product => [801,808])` with no luck

Comment: I tried to do the following -- User.where(:product => [801,808]) with no luck

Comment: Is the information coming from a database? What is the structure? Are you looking for an SQL query? What database are you using?

Comment: postgres doing a query. this is what comes out for ex. user.products.inspect gives accessible_product_ids:
0: 799
1: 800
2: 801
3: 799
4: 844
5: 821
6: 105
7: 192
8: 194
9: 85
10: 35
11: 31
12: 625
13: 363
14: 813

Comment: Check this [blog](http://rny.io/rails/postgresql/2013/07/28/tagging-in-rails-4-using-postgresql-arrays.html), more specifically the **Querying** section

Comment: As a side note, before running a quick script on the production console make sure you do a database backup! If you are using Heroku, [see here for info on doing a backup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups) (just do `heroku pg:backups capture`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have too many objects in your database and you want to run a quick one-off script in the console you can do this:

```rb
desired_product_ids = [801, 808]
User.find_each do |user|
  unless (user.product_ids & desired_product_ids).empty?
    give_gift user
  end
end

def give_gift(user)
  # your gift logic
  user.save
end
```

This will load all your active record User objects in memory in batches so it will take a long time if your database is large.

I would recommend using a `where` query like NEO-xx suggested. You can combine that with the `find_each`:

```
User.where(<your condition here>).find_each do |user|
  give_gift user
end
```

Comment: this worked for me! thanks for the point in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

If you have two models as User and Product . something like this should solve your problem

```
product_ids = [801, 808]
User.joins(:products).where(products: {id: product_ids})
```

Comment: thanks! in this case its a small array that the user model already contains

Comment: can you update question with your User model structure ?